# Backcolor not Coloring Entire Cell only Text

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors, cell, textchanged

For the internet I pulled and amended some code to change the backcolor of the current cell in a datagridview upon editing the text. The problem is, the backcolor only seems to change within the cells text and not the entire cell (there seems to be a 3 pixel margin in the cell that has the original color). Below is the code I'm using:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim a, b As Integer
Dim myvalue As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    a = 0
    Do While a < 10
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        a += 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private EditingControl As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    EditingControl = e.Control
    AddHandler EditingControl.TextChanged, AddressOf EditingControl_TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub EditingControl_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    EditingControl.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    If EditingControl IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler EditingControl.TextChanged, AddressOf EditingControl_TextChanged
    End If
    EditingControl = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

Does anybody know what I've done wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditingControl` is put on a panel and has a 3 pixels margin.

Colouring the parent panel solves your problem :

```
Private Sub EditingControl_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    EditingControl.BackColor = Color.White
    EditingControl.Parent.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

By the way, `DataGridView` class already has an `EditingControl` property.